# Remove arrows and done button from WebView footer react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I remove the arrows and the done button from the header?

I'm using `WebView` library from `react-native`

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ width: 500, height: 500, marginTop: 40 }}>
            <WebView
                ref="AddressSearchWebView"
                source={{ html: HTML }}
                javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                onMessage={(e) => {
                    var eventData = JSON.parse(e.nativeEvent.data);
                    this.props.onSearch(eventData);
                }}
            >
            </WebView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass [hidekeyboardaccessoryview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#hidekeyboardaccessoryview) as a property to `WebView` component.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to hide the navigation buttons at the bottom. But, you can always trick the system by adding a negative margin to the WebView. You'll have to play around with the exact number but adding something like `style={{marginBottom:-50}}` should do the trick.